# I would like to create a textView surrounded rounded circle the diagram as shown below

Tags: android, textview, rounded-corners

I would like to create a `textView` surrounded rounded circle the diagram as shown below:

Image Link :-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0cMB.png

Can anyone of you let me know how to do this?

Comment: Took a drawable as a background

Comment: best approach to create the view using xml.

Comment: Champandorid  i have to set the text to textview in that image.so that's why i didn't take that as drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this how to implement the above image requirement.
 Your Layout data should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#004473">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_corner_shape"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="01"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_circle_shape"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="Lorum Ipusum"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Drawable files data:

**linear_layout_corner_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#004473"></solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"></stroke>

<corners android:radius="30dp"></corners>
```

**textview_circle_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"></solid>
```